# T SQL How to convert Varchar to Date

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, type-conversion

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016.

I have a field 'MyDate' in table 'MyTable'.  It contains dates in varchar(10) in the format dd/mm/yyyy e.g. 21/01/2020

How do I convert these to SQL Datetime format?

I have tried:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(MyDate as date), 103) as 'dd/mm/yyyy' from MyTable
```

and

```
select FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, MyDate, 21), 'dd/MM/yyyy') FROM MyTable
```

But receive the error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The first `CONVERT` argument is the data type after conversion so you want `CONVERT(date, MyDate, 103)`.

Comment: @DanGuzman You are right and it will solve the problem.

Comment: @DanGuzman but now I just get the date in YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a format, @Michael , they are stored as binary values. It's up to your presentation layer to define the format that are displayed in.

Comment: `I have a field 'MyDate' in table 'MyTable'. It contains dates in varchar(10)` that's a serious bug. Dates have no format. Use the correct type eg `date` or `datetime2` and let the client decide how to display them. You simply **can't** recover correct dates from strings - what if some other buggy code mixed up string formats? What if the same field contains `13/04/2020` and `04/13/2020`. Worse, what if it's `04/07/2020`, is that April 7th or July 4th? Fix the data type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand where you are coming from but we don't live in a perfect world and the data is from a third party system that I have no control over

Comment: @Michael this isn't a matter of perfection. It's a fundamental problem - that format can't be sorted chronologically, so range queries won't work at all. Indexes will be useless for anything other than point queries. You'll have to take that into account when querying that field.

Comment: @Michael if cast that string to a `date` in the `WHERE` clause, the server will have to scan the *entire* table to calculate those values - there's no way around this. This in turn locks the entire table with share locks. That's another thing you have to keep in mind

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your input - I will take on-board what you have highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of the below queries.

```
Select CONVERT(date, '21/01/2020', 103)
SELECT Cast(convert(varchar, convert(date, '21/01/2020', 105), 101) as date)
SELECT cast(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('21/01/2020',10),105),101) as date);
```

A sample output will look like as shown in the image.

[image]

You can find the [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=16b8b118752ab4af338f6c29c3791fba).

Answer (score 0):

You nee to convert it to date time .
Please try below query

```
   select CONVERT(datetime, '21/01/2020', 103) as 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```